# Subselecting features in QGIS

Tags: qgis, features, subset

Is there a way to subselect features in QGIS as can be done in ArcMap?

For example, I have 5 features selected, and I want to look at each one of them individually (e.g.: zoom to), without unselecting the other 4.

In QGIS when I have a selection, I lose the rest of the selected features if you click on any one of the selected features. I want to be able to subselect (i.e.: create a selection within a selection).

Comment: You mean to select selected features (they become yellow), to get two "levels" of selections?

Comment: Yes that is what I want, 2 levels of selection.

Comment: Your first "selection" could be by using a field filter, and then from that you could make individual selections.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a sub-selection when you are displaying the attribute table in form view.

You can switch to form view using the lower right icon.

Once you have a selection, you can click on the **name** of the feature of interest. Note that if you click on the yellow square, it will replace the entire selection.

You may want to play with the `auto zoom` or `auto pan` to achieve these actions on the sub-selection.

Also, displaying only the selected features will ease the process.

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, that is exactly what I wanted. I also just learnt how to adjust the selection transparency in Project Properties so I can see the imagery under the selected polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> down while clicking and it will add or remove from the selection.

Comment: I think that the OP is interested in making a selection *within* a selection, i.e. a "subselection".